# Trouble in C with string array where elements are repeated

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, fgets

I'm trying to take an unknown amount of lines of console input, convert each line to a String using malloc, and then add each string to an array of strings by dynamically reallocating memory each time. My goal is to have an array where each element is a different line entered by the console (the while loop should end with EOF).

My code is below.

```
char * inputString = (char *)malloc(100);
char * aWord = (char *)malloc(1);
char ** listWords = (char **)malloc(1);
int wordCount = 0;

while (fgets(inputString, 100, stdin) != NULL)
{       
    wordCount++;
    *(inputString + (strlen(inputString) - 1)) = '\0';
    aWord = (char *)realloc(aWord, strlen(inputString) + 1);
    aWord = inputString;

    listWords = realloc(listWords, sizeof(char) * wordCount);
    *(listWords + (wordCount - 1)) = aWord;
}

for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++)
    printf("%s\n", listWords[i]);
```

If I were to input in console

```
abc\n
b\n
cad\n
^Z\n
```

In theory, I would like my code to print out

```
abc\n
b\n
cad\n
```

Each line of console input. Instead it prints

```
cad\n
cad\n
cad\n
```

The last line entered. Help much appreciated

Comment: arg no: `aWord = (char *)realloc(aWord, strlen(inputString) + 1);
    aWord = inputString;
` you're losing the allocated buffer each. Consider a copy instead.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: All elements of `inputString` point to the same string `inputString`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy a string using an assignment, you have to use `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy(aWord, inputString);
```

Also,

```
*(listWords + (wordCount - 1)) = aWord;
```

can be simplified to:

```
listWords[wordCount-1] = aWord;
```

Answer (score 1):

First is this:

```
aWord = (char *)realloc(aWord, strlen(inputString) + 1);
aWord = inputString;
```

Here you allocate space for `aWord`, but then overwrite the returned address with the address contained in `inputString`.  So each string you read in ends up overwriting the previous string.  You also should be using `malloc` instead of `realloc` because you want to get a new buffer instead of resusing an existing one.

Change the `realloc` call to `malloc and instead of assigning one pointer to the other, use`strcpy` to copy it.

```
aWord = malloc(strlen(inputString) + 1);
strcpy(aWord, inputString);
```

Then on this line:

```
listWords = realloc(listWords, sizeof(char) * wordCount);
```

You only allocate enough memory for an array of characters instead of an array of *pointers* to characters.  This results in writing past the end of allocated memory, invoking [undefined beahvior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The proper allocation is:

```
listWords = realloc(listWords, sizeof(char *) * wordCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues.

First, `realloc` does not allocate an additional `aWord` but increases/decreases the buffer of the current `aWord`, thereby probably giving back a new address while releasing the old one. So `aWord = (char *)realloc(aWord, strlen(inputString) + 1)` will adapt the memory to a new size, but you will loose the content written to `aWord` previously. Note that `*(listWords + (wordCount - 1)) = aWord` will let your final list point to `aWord`. Use `malloc` instead of `realloc`.

Second, with `aWord = inputString;`, you let `aWord` point to `inputString` instead of copying its contents. Use `strcpy` instead:

```
char *aWord = malloc(aWord, strlen(inputString) + 1);
strcpy (aWord,inputString);
```

Third, you need to reserve space for character pointers, not just characters.

```
listWords = realloc(listWords, sizeof(char*) * wordCount);
```